# Hypothesis test question

Tags: probability, statistics

Can anyone check my answer about the following hypothesis test?

> A company considers buying a machine to manufacture a certain item.
>   When tested, 28 out of 600 items produced by the machine were found
>   defective. Does the data support the hypothesis that the defect rate
>   of the machine is smaller than 3% at the 5% significance level.
>
> $H_0: p \ge 0.03$
>
> $H_a: p < 0.03$
>
> $\alpha = 0.05$
>
> Critical value $z = -1.645$
>
> Reject $H_0$ if $z < -1.645$
>
> Test statistic
>
> $\Rightarrow Z_0 = \frac{\overline{X} - \mu_o}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} =
> > \frac{0.0467-0.03}{0.03*0.97/\sqrt{600}} = 14.057$
>
> Therefore, we fail to reject $H_0$. There isn't enough evidence to say
>   that defect rate of machine is smaller than 3%.

Thanks!

Comment: But you have not stated the value of $\sigma$, nor whether you know the population value, or if you obtained $\sigma$ from sample data, in which case your statistic would be a $t-$statistic.

Comment: Sorry, I just mean that you did not mention $\sigma$ in the statement of the problem.

Comment: BFD:Proportions hyposthesis testing, you don't need a sigma

Answer (score 0):

H0: p=.03

H1: p<.03

p0=.03

p-hat = .0467 = 28/600

Test statistic => z = (0.0467 - 0.03)/sqrt(0.03*.97/600) = 2.398

z>-1.65 (One tailed test with alpha = .05)

Hence fail to reject H0 to conclude that there is not sufficient evidence that the defect

rate is smaller than 3%

Sorry, I changed the solution